# How can I kill one evaluator from another?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, kernel

I have a kernel named A in one notebook and other notebook with kernel B, how can I kill B from A?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From notebook A execute this:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{ExpressionCell[Defer[Quit[]], "Input", 
    Evaluator -> "B"]}]; SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook]
SelectionEvaluate[nb]
NotebookClose[nb]
```

Comment: @M.R. , is it possible to use a similar trick when running codes in 2 distinct kernels A and B, using 2 distinct Linux terminals?